# Micropedia Talmudit

Tags: talmud-gemara, product-recommendation

Does anyone have any experience learning with Micropedia Talmudit?

Is it too much of an abridgement of the full version to be of serious use for someone studying Gemara?

Comment: It is available online. I have found it quite helpful https://www.yeshiva.org.il/wiki/index.php/%D7%95%D7%99%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%91%D7%94:%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%A7%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A4%D7%93%D7%99%D7%94_%D7%AA%D7%9C%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%93%D7%99%D7%AA

Comment: On a related note, this article claims that the full Encyclopedia Talmudit will be finished by 2024 - https://www.jpost.com/judaism/article-709619

Comment: Excellent, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [here](https://talmudit18.wixsite.com/talmudit/micropedia) where it outlines the goals of the Micropedia Talmudit, which will hopefully provide some answer to your question:

> The goals of the Talmudic Micropedia are:
>
> A) to define, explore and clarify all halachic issues.
>
> B) to present a precise picture of the principles and rules of all halachic issues discussed in the Talmudic Encyclopedia in a more concise and friendly way.
>
> C) To summarize and simplify the entries Talmudic Encyclopedia, so that on the one hand it preserves the great reliability of the information, and on the other hand the style and layout of the material will allow even a scholar who is not regularly engaged in Torah study to understand the concepts of halacha.
>
> H) To add issues of modern, contemporary halachic literature that is relevant to the entries.
>
> I) To write the different entries ​​according to targeted audience, i.e., entries ​​that have an interest to a wide audience or of significance in the yeshiva world are relative long, whereas entries that the majority of the public are not familiar with are relatively brief.
>
> This work of the Talmudic Micropedia will become an important and most reliable source for comprehending halachic matters in an accessible and understandable way.

​(I don't know why it jumps from 'C' to 'H'?)

Comment: This is helpful. Thank you. Have you found that the series lives up to these goals?

Comment: I have never seen it properly, only heard of it.

Comment: Understood, thank you.